# Only parse necessary html data and skip unwanted html data

Tags: javascript, html, json, xmlhttprequest, html-parsing

I am working on a script that gets a url and parses all of its html. But it only uses the "data-style-name" "href" "data-sold-out" and the "select".

this is how I parse the html:

```
function loadHTMLSource(urlSource) {
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", urlSource, false);
    xhttp.send();
    return xhttp.response;
}

var page_html = loadHTMLSource(url); 

parser = new DOMParser();

my_document = parser.parseFromString(page_html, "text/html");
```

and Im only pulling info from these html things

```
my_document.querySelectorAll("[data-style-name]");

attributes["data-sold-out"].value

my_document.querySelector("meta[name='csrf-token']");

my_document.querySelector('select');
```

Is it possible to pull only these certain html things. So I don't end up pulling data that I don't need?

Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: What do you mean by "pull"?

Comment: if that's the only payload yo can get, then you have to dig through it.

Comment: well im not sure if its the only way to get html data, that is why im asking, what is the most efficent and fast way to pull html data and only certain ones @dandavis